# How to perform gridsearch on pipeline with transformer that takes function as parameter?

Tags: methods, parameters, scikit-learn, pipeline

I've built a pipeline that extracts some features and then performs a Stochastic Gradient Descent. The transformer takes a method as parameter. Now I want to perform a gridsearch on the parameters of the SGD. But I get the following error:
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : it's not found as **builtin**.instancemethod

I think it can't pickle because the input is a method. Is there a way that I can edit my transformer so that it works?

```
class extraFeature(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
def __init__(self, func):
    self.func = func

def transform(self, X, y=None):
    #Use function passed in pipeline
    ret = [self.func(sentence) for sentence in X]
    ret = np.array(normalize(ret)[0]).reshape(len(ret),1)
    return ret

def fit(self, X, y=None):
    return self

Pipeline([
    ('features',FeatureUnion([
        ('words',Pipeline([   
        ('vect', CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2))),                                           
        ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True))                                               
        ])),
       ('fleshReadingEase',extraFeature(textstat.flesch_reading_ease)),
       ('smogIndex',extraFeature(textstat.smog_index))
    ])),
    ('clf',SGDClassifier(learning_rate='optimal',eta0=0.001,class_weight='balanced',loss='modified_huber', penalty='l2',alpha=1e-3, n_iter=5, random_state=42))
])
```

Comment: Can you post the complete code for gridsearch and the stack trace? Also have you tried gridsearch directly without pickling?